# AWS AppSync - GraphQL API Mapping Template Error

Tags: c#, graphql, aws-appsync, webapi, vtl

I am trying to integrate my GraphQL Web API with AppSync. But I am getting the following error

```
"errorType": "MappingTemplate",
"message": "Template transformation yielded an empty response."
```

My Data Source HTTP end Point is : https://mybooking123.com

My Query is:

```
mutation
{
    Booking(ID:111,BusNumber:"AAAA1", comment:"None")
   {
     BusNumber
     PassngerName
     TravelDate
     TravelTime
     ValidityDate
     ValidaityTime
     ErrorCode
  }
}: [BookingResponse]
```

**Schema**

```
type Mutation {
    Booking(
       ID: Int!,
       BusNumber: String,
       comment: String
       ): [BookingResponse]
  }


 type BookingResponse 
 {
    BusNumber: String
    PassngerName: String
    BookingDate: String
    BookingTime: String
    ValidityDate: String
    ValidaityTime: String
    ErrorCode: Int
 }
```

**AppSync - Request Mapping Template**

```
{
  "version": "2018-05-29",
  "method": "POST",
   "resourcePath": "/GraphQL",
  "params":{
     "query":$util.toJson($ctx.args),
      "headers": {
        "Authorization": "$ctx.request.headers.Authorization"
  }
 }
}
```

**AppSync - Response Mapping Template**

```
## Raise a GraphQL field error in case of a datasource invocation error
#if($ctx.error)
   $util.error($ctx.error.message, $ctx.error.type)
#end
## If the response is not 200 then return an error. Else return the body **
#if($ctx.result.statusCode == 200)
   #set($body = $util.parseJson($ctx.result.body))
   $util.toJson($body) ##make it $body.data depending on the return on your rest api
#else
   $utils.appendError($ctx.result.body, "$ctx.result.statusCode")
#end
```

My GraphQL API is working with out AppSync. But I want to implement AppSync to access the GraphQL API. I am not sure what's wrong with the template mapping. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be with the `$utils.appendError` VTL method (line 10 of the Response Mapping Template).

Based on your Response mapping template, if there is an error in the Velocity parsing, AppSync will throw an error (line 2).

If there is no error, the Velocity parser will evaluate the response (`$ctx.result`) and send back the `body` if the `statusCode` is equal to 200. So far so good. The problem is if the `statusCode` is different from 200 (line 9).

In that case, AppSync should also throw an error. But you are using the `$util.appendError`. In that case, VTL will add error information to the context and will keep working to generate the result template. But because it does not do anything after this step, the generated template is empty (Template transformation yielded an empty response.).

the info from [AppSync Resolver Mapping Util docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/resolver-util-reference.html):

> $util.appendError(String)
>
> Appends a custom error. This can be used in request or response mapping templates if the template detects an error with the request or with the invocation result. Unlike $util.error(String), the template evaluation will not be interrupted, so that data can be returned to the caller.

In GraphQL is possible to have a response that has a part that was successful and a part that was an error. That happens because the response probably is coming from two different resolvers. If one of them worked in the other doesn't, you can get the response both responses in the final GraphQL response. In that scenario, AppSync will add the success response to the expected GraphQL field and add the error to the context.

To solve your issue, instead of using `$util.appendError` use `$util.error` in line 10. With that, if your call failed, AppSync will add the error information and halt the VLT execution instead of try to perform the next steps to yield the result.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried your input and after slightly updated the template mapping . Now I am getting the error while running the  query: ""Trailing characters at the end of the JSON string are not allowed."